# Using jquery's setInterval on cronjob

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm starting to mess around Cronjobs and I hit a brick wall. What I want is to call the cronjob every X minutes and in that script there will be javascript that calls ajax every second for the next 60 seconds. Ajax calls one php function that writes something in the database. I was wondering is it even possible to use setInterval in cronjob script or not. I know that the script is working because when I call it manually it works. And cronjob script is good because I made a test query inside of it and it works. Here is the script.
If I can't use setInterval, is there any alternative to do the described task.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timesRun = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        timesRun += 1;
        if(timesRun === 60) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cron_script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(output) {
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling ajax and other php script I can just call it inside cronjob and use `sleep();`

```
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i < 61; $i++) {

        // my query
        sleep(1);

    }
?>
```